# Android app cryptography does it fall under US Export laws?

Tags: aes, xor

Basically, I want to encrypt some strings in my app, strings like access tokens or passwords. I planned on using AES, and mainly saw a good library at https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto. Note that this is used only for protection of sensitive data while the app's purpose is other. As I said, simply add a bit of extra security to saved tokens if a root-ed user gains access to the database which stores these values.

However, after reading a bit about cryptography it seems that there are some US Export laws to consider for apps published on Google Play and available to other countries outside US.

Does using AES library in the link above fall under the requirements of US Export laws or because it uses the integrated android libraries and not uses own cryptography library is fine? Or maybe using xor would be better?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you plan on selling this app?

Comment: @SEJPM The app is free with parts locked which get unlock by using in app purchase mechanism.

Comment: If you are seriously worried, I strongly recommend you a) check the official documentation of the US Department of Commerce or whatever they call themselves now b) ask a lawyer professioned in these matters and for a quick and cheap answer ask on Law StackExchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about law and not about cryptography as defined in our help center.